# Is a final yield return 0 required in corutines?

Tags: unity, coroutines

I have the following code run in a coroutine.

I would like to know if the last yield return 0 is necessary and why.

Thank you!

```
private IEnumerator pChangeFoV()
{
    float duration = 0.7f;
    float zValue = 5f;

    for (float t = 0f; t < duration; t += Time.deltaTime)
    {
        float fNew = Mathf.Lerp(_camera.fieldOfView, zValue, t / duration);
        _camera.fieldOfView = fNew;
        yield return 0;
    }
    _camera.fieldOfView = zValue; //make sure we're really where we want to be

    //now do everything that should be done after we're done with this coroutine

    pEnableSomeScripts();

    yield return 0; //is this final yield return 0 required???
 }
```

Comment: No. Because https://answers.unity.com/questions/233010/yield-and-coroutines-how-do-the-actually-work.html and https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerator?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Did you try deleting it to see what happens? ;)

Comment: Specifically to your case it might be important, but my comment was about general case.